Automaton $\sum=$ {a, b, c } - even positions in which there are more letters $a$ than $b$
Is there a deterministic automaton that recognizes the language of these words over the alphabet $\sum = \{a, b, c \}$, in which there are more $a$ on even positions than $b$?
I was trying to take a subset of this language, e.g. $a^{2n} b^n$, and show from the pumping lemma that it is not regular but (as I know) I still do not show that the entire language is irregular.

Hint: if it's regular, then the language of words with more $a$s than $b$s is also regular.

You are asking for a "deterministic automaton" but what I see you are looking for a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine ?

Yes, of course.
But when I read your question, I interpret you are asking for a automaton that recognizes a regular language, a finite automaton.
If so:
No.
The restriction to even positions is irrelevant, as you can construct an automaton that ignores odd positions.
Then, the question reduces to: is there an automaton that decides if there are more a than b.
As there can be an arbitrary number of a's before b's (and the other way round), the automaton must be able to "count" the a's, and therefore cannot be finite.

Hi. Thanks for help. I have similar thoughts as you but I can't figure any formal prove :(

Suppose that the language, call it $L_1$, is regular. Define
$$L_2 := \{a^{2n}b^{2m} : n, m \ge 0\}.$$
It's not difficult to construct a finite state machine that recognises $L_2$, so I won't do it. It is definitely regular. As a regular expression, it would be $(aa)^*(bb)^*$.
The intersection of these languages must therefore be regular. We have:
$$L_1 \cap L_2 = \{a^{2n}b^{2m} : n \ge m\}.$$
This language, however, is not regular, and the pumping lemma seems easier to apply to it than to $L_1$. If we take $a^{2n}b^{2n}$ for sufficiently large $n$, then we have three possibilities for the pumpable substring:

If it consists of all $a$s, then remove it, reducing the $a$s below the $b$s.
If it consists of all $b$s, then add another copy, increasing the $b$s above the $a$s.
If it consists of both $a$s and $b$s, then add another copy, which stops it being of the form $a^*b^*$.

In any case, we can pump the pumpable substring in such a way that the resulting string does not belong to $L_1 \cap L_2$, proving $L_1 \cap L_2$ is not regular. Hence, by contradiction, $L_1$ is not regular.
